# Align & save structure segment only

Tags: python, biopython

I am trying to align a short segment within structure A to a short structure B.
I tried following ["Protein Superposition using Biopython"](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/moac/people/students/peter_cock/python/protein_superposition/)

But because I only want to a short segment from A and save this one, I am getting problems saving the results.

Calling alignment works fine:

```
super_imposer.set_atoms(residuesBCA,residuesACA)
```

and the consecutive transformation to the alignment position runs through

```
for residue in residuesACA:
    residue.transform(super_imposer.rotran[0],super_imposer.rotran[1])
```

but I cannot check the result because I cannot save the residues with

```
io = PDBIO()  
io.set_structure(residuesACA)
io.save('./' + pdbFile)
```

`io` here expects a full structure, but in the previous loop I only transformed the segment residues. How can I save them to disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PDBIO` indeed expects a full structure. The trick to saving only a subset of that structure is using a [`Select`](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.PDB.PDBIO%27.Select-class.html) class. If you override any of the default methods (`accept_chain`, `accept_residue`, etc.) you can override which aspects of the SMCRA hierarchy are saved.

```
from Bio import PDB

class OnlyACAResideus(PDB.Select):
    def accept_residue(self, res):
        return res in residuesACA

io = PDBIO()

# Presumably, you still have the structure, but you can unfold it like so:
struct = PDB.Selection.unfold_entities(residuesACA, 'S')[0]
io.set_structure(struct)
io.save("struct.pdb", select=OnlyACAResidues())
```